# Instagram clone. when clicking a button, Why can't I go back to the previous fragment?

Tags: kotlin, button, fragment

I could really use your help with this one.
I'm making an Instagram clone and I'm using fragments, I have one for the profile page. In it, I have a button that goes to AccountSettingsActivity, where you can edit your user information, I have a button to save the changes and another to return to the profile fragment, but when I use the latter the app crashes and this message appears:

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {academy.epicprogramming.kynoanimalrescue/academy.epicprogramming.kynoanimalrescue.fragments.ProfileFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

and this is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="academy.epicprogramming.kynoanimalrescue">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<!--        <activity-->
<!--            android:name=".Main2Activity"-->
<!--            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"></activity>-->
    <activity android:name=".AccountSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBYtQl--ajXZy1uzOZoXSNGJLCeyAHUV9s" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".Login.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.SignInActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Intro.IntroSlider" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/> <!-- optional (needed if default theme         has no action bar) -->

</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the button to go back to the ProfileFragment file

```
close_profile_btn.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, ProfileFragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

and this is the complete AccountSettingsActivity file

```
class AccountSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
private var checker = ""
private var myUrl = ""
private var imageUri: Uri? = null
private var storageProfilePictureRef: StorageReference? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_settings)


    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    storageProfilePictureRef =
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Profile Pictures")

    logout_btn.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()

        val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, ProfileFragment::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    close_profile_btn.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, ProfileFragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    change_image_text_btn.setOnClickListener {
        checker = "clicked"

        CropImage.activity()
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(this@AccountSettingsActivity)
    }

    save_info_profile_btn.setOnClickListener {
        if (checker == "clicked") {
            updateImageAndInfo()
        } else {
            updateUserInfoOnly()
        }
    }

    userInfo()
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE  &&  resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK  &&  data != null)
    {
        val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
        imageUri = result.uri
        profile_image_view_profile_frag.setImageURI(imageUri)
    }
}


private fun updateUserInfoOnly() {

    when {
        full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please enter your name",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        username_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please enter your username",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
            bio_profile_frag.setText("Estoy usando Kyno animal rescue")
            val usersRef =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
            val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
            userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString().toLowerCase()
            userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
            userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()

            usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Account information successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()

            val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        else -> {
            val usersRef =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
            val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
            userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString().toLowerCase()
            userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
            userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()

            usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Account information successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()

            val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

}
private fun userInfo() {
    val usersRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseUser.uid)
    usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java)
                Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                    .into(profile_image_view_profile_frag)
                full_name_profile_frag.setText(user.getFullname())
                username_profile_frag.setText(user.getUsername())
                bio_profile_frag.setText(user.getBio())
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}

private fun updateImageAndInfo() {

    when {
        imageUri == null -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please choose a picture",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please enter your name",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        username_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Please enter your username",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

        bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please enter your bio",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }

//            CODE TO SET A DEFAULT BIO IF USER DOESN'T ENTER ONE
//            bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
//                bio_profile_frag.setText("Estoy usando Kyno animal rescue")
//
//                val usersRef =
//                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
//                val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
//                userMap["fullname"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString().toLowerCase()
//                userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
//                userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()
//
//                usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)
//
//                Toast.makeText(this, "Account information successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                    .show()
//
//                val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
//                startActivity(intent)
//                finish()
//            }
        else -> {
            val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
            progressDialog.setTitle("Account Settings")
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while your profile updates")
            progressDialog.show()

            val fileRef = storageProfilePictureRef!!.child(firebaseUser!!.uid + ".jpg")

            var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
            uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>{ task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                }
                return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl
            }).addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<Uri> {task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    val downloadUrl = task.result
                    myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                        val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        userMap["fullname"] =
                            full_name_profile_frag.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString()
                        userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()
                        userMap["image"] = myUrl

                        ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                        Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Account information successfully updated",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            )
                            .show()

                        val intent =
                            Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()

                        progressDialog.dismiss()

                    } else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }

                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**`Fragment cannot be started using Intent.`**

you have to do following

```
supportFragmentManager
          .beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.root_layout, ProfileFragment.newInstance(), "")
          .commit()
```

> Here add() method first parameter is the container where you want to
>   load the fragment whose id you is to be provided, second parameter is
>   the fragment which is to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find explicit activity class {academy.epicprogramming.kynoanimalrescue/academy.epicprogramming.kynoanimalrescue.fragments.ProfileFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

if this is the problem then you must define activity in manifest file

you need to  define like rest of activities.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man this was so simple, after trying so much stuff I came across a comment somewhere in Stack that said, "you don't need to have an Intent, just call finish()" and yeah that was the answer